# AOP implementation

Tags: java, aop

What is the best way to have your own home-grown Java-based implementation of Aspect-Oriented-Programming?

P.S.: The possible argument would be to use Spring AOP, but I have a project that is not Spring based, and has to be that way (and hence have to fallback to my own implementation).

Comment: What language/platform are you using?

Comment: that would be Java. updated in the question as well.

Comment: Do you want to implement it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using dynamic proxies generated from interfaces:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2000/jw-1110-proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you use AspectJ ? ( http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/ )

Comment: Ok, so let's start with the raw bytecode manipulation... but beware: it's a mess! (you can use `http://asm.ow2.org/` to help yourself with the bytecode manipulation)

Comment: I was about to suggest it. Then I'm out of ideas. Maybe your only choice would be creating your own programming language using Java and then applying AOP to that language.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on not using any thirdparty libraries (which is, I believe, a bad idea in general), you will be probably interested in java.lang.reflect.Proxy class. 
It can be used as a basis (quite poor, but better than nothing) for implementing aspect oriented framework. Maybe this just would be enough for your needs.
Good luck!